# knitr to PDF not wrapping comments

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr, margin

When trying to knit my Rmarkdown files to PDF, `knitr` doesn't seem to wrap the comments and the text just goes outside of the pdf margins.

I have tried specifying several parameters but nothing seems to have any effect.

````
---
title: "Demo margin"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(width=80)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,out.width = 40, tidy=T, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60))
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars, out.width=80, tidy = 'formatR', tidy.opts = list(blank = FALSE, width.cutoff = 60)}
summary(cars)
#very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very incredibly very long comment
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.1  htmltools_0.4.0 tools_3.6.1     yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.3     
 [6] rmarkdown_2.0   knitr_1.26      xfun_0.11       digest_0.6.23   rlang_0.4.2    
[11] evaluate_0.14
```

**How can I get `knitr` to wrap the comments within the margins?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed after installing R v4.0.0 and reinstalling packages.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] formatR_1.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.0  htmltools_0.4.0 tools_4.0.0     yaml_2.2.1      Rcpp_1.0.4.6    rmarkdown_2.1   knitr_1.28      xfun_0.13       digest_0.6.25   rlang_0.4.6     evaluate_0.14
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you didn't have the **formatR** package installed. If that is the case, you need to `install.packages('formatR')`. Here is what I get on my computer:

[image: comments rewrapped by formatR]

Comment: I have installed and launched the library and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Please verify if you have successfully installed **formatR** by putting `library(formatR)` in a code chunk in your Rmd document.

Comment: Yes I did that and it made no difference, I just tried it again I obtain the same result. It must be another issue...

Comment: That's weird. Although I believe R 3.6.1 should work, it is not the latest version of R. Perhaps a blind shot in the dark would be upgrading R and retry...

Comment: No luck so far, I have reinstalled R and all the packages, and still have the same issue. I can replicate it on other laptops as well that just had a fresh R installation. Could it be due to Windows or MiKTeX?

Comment: I uninstalled MikTeX and reinstalled tinytex but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It is irrelevant to LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and even with exhaustive searching found no other solution than either:

- Break the comment manually into shorter lines
- Use paste0("foo ... ", "... bar")